# button href is ignoring everything after question mark

Tags: html, url

I have this button

```
<button href="account.html?gto=4356">go to</button>
```

On click it redirects to `./account.html?#` though i was expecting `./account.html?gto=4356`.

Why is it ignoring everything after the question mark and how can I make this work?

Comment: Put your button in a `form` and use button attributes formaction, formmethod (get in your case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button tag does not support `href` attribute. instead use `a` tag and css design to make it look like a button.

```
<a href="account.html?gto=4356">go to</a>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with Javascript

```
<button onclick='goto()'>go to</button>
<script>
function goto(){
location.replace("account.html?gto=4356");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Have to do it like this

```html
<button><a href="/account.html?gto=4356">go to</a></button>
```

I hope this works for you! regards